# What does the default value object in the constructor for FrameworkPropertyMetadata actually do?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was wondering what kind of default this is actually setting. I thought maybe it would set a default value for the property so that I wouldn't need to set one in my constructor, but that is not the case. Very curious what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 3):

> . I thought maybe it would set a default value for the property so that I wouldn't need to set one in my constructor, but that is not the case.

That is actually the case.

If you don't specify a value for a `DependencyProperty`, the default specified in the metadata is returned by the dependency system.  This is nice since the class instances themselves don't actually use storage for this value unless it's set (other than the single default instance).

From the [documentation for `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557298.aspx), the `defaultValue` constructor argument provides:

> The default value of the dependency property, usually provided as a value of a specific type.

Comment: huh interesting. Now i have to go look at what I did again. It wasn't seeming to act as the default, so i must have had something wrong